# .Net UDP using multithreading

Tags: .net

I have several vehicles that send a data via GPS to the server after every 10 seconds and the server should be listening and decode the data to store in the database (Sql Server). There will be hundreds of entries per minute. I have a single threaded code for now which is not really helpful. Few entries get dropped off during the process time of one entry. I want to create a multithreaded code so that when one thread is busy processing, the packet is moved to the next available thread.

To my knowledge and after looking into several forums, I realized that "yield" would help solving this issue. But I could not find proper examples as to how yield can be used?

Can someone help me with this by posting some examples?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend setting an async callback on the receive, then push the data onto a queue, from there process out of the queue on another thread. Make sure to lock that queue or use ConcurrentQueue so you don't bump the threads together.

Comment: This is correct. Just listen for udp packets and add them to a queue. use an autoresetevent to signal that new data is available in the queue. Don't forget to lock the queue.

Comment: Thanks very much. What if I have a situation where I need to create only 5 threads and each time a packet comes in, it should be assigned to the oldest thread and once the processing of that packet is done, the thread should kill itself and a new thread should be created?

Comment: I don't think you really need to get into that level of complication. I would see you have 2 threads at this point, the thread receiving data and the thread processing data from the queue. The idea is receive data as quickly as possible, queue it, then put your long running logic (i.e. Database) on another thread. The queue will maintain the order of receipt so it can take as long as needed to process.